# Unable to set directive input value

Tags: angular, directive

I have narrowed down the problem I'm having to this directive code:

```ts
@Directive({
  selector: '[tdStepTracker]'
})
export class StepTrackerDirective {
  @Input('tdStepTracker') keyName: string;

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('keyName', this.keyName);
  }
}
```

And being used here:

```ts
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <h2 [tdStepTracker]="something">Hello {{name}}</h2>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'
  }
}
```

When I log the contents of `this.keyName` I get `undefined`. I was expecting to get `something` instead.

Here's a link to the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/Cbw6CHbsppiuVpW4kpTh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you want to pass a string

```ts
<h2 [tdStepTracker]="something">Hello {{name}}</h2>
```

should be changed to one of

```ts
<h2 [tdStepTracker]="'something'">Hello {{name}}</h2>
<h2 tdStepTracker="something">Hello {{name}}</h2>
```

Your code binds to a property `something` of class `App` which doesn't exist.

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/GyOTXU02FiYZrinuS8qr?p=preview)